# grails OpenPGP decryption not working

Tags: grails, encryption, openpgp

I am making use of the Grails Plugin: crypto:2.0 and I am having problems with encrypting decrypting a message in PGP.

Here is my controller code:

```
def index3 () {

    def pgpK = PGP.generateKeyPair()
    String encodedPublic = pgpK.encodedPublicKey
    String encodedPrivate = pgpK.encodedPrivateKey

    PGP pgp = new PGP (encodedPublic, encodedPrivate)

    String message = "Hello World"

    String encodeStr = pgp.encryptArmored(message)

    println(encodeStr)

    String decryptStr = pgp.decrypt(encodeStr.getBytes()).toString()

    println(decryptStr)

}
```

When executed, it shows me the encrypted message as armored PGP.  However, when I use the armored encrypted message and decrypt it always returns null.

Has anyone out there encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
    def pgpK = PGP.generateKeyPair()
    String encodedPublic = pgpK.encodedPublicKey
    String encodedPrivate = pgpK.encodedPrivateKey

    PGP pgp = new PGP (encodedPublic, encodedPrivate)

    String message = "Hello World"

    String encodeStr = pgp.encryptArmored(message)

    println(encodeStr)

    String decryptStr = new String(pgp.decrypt(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(encodeStr.getBytes())).getBytes()))

    println(decryptStr)
```